# Ruby - Twitter Gem - Uploading image using INIT, APPEND and FINALIZE command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, twitter, rubygems

I am trying to upload a simple image to Twitter using both `Twitter gem` and Twitter REST API. I always get the following error `Twitter::Error::BadRequest: Segments do not add up to provided total file size.`

If I am right, I understand that at the end of the process (FINALIZE), the size of my uploaded image (during the APPEND) is the not the same I declared in the first place (during the INIT).

Here is my code:

```
file_path = "/Users/folder/image.png"
filesize = File.open(file_path).size
init_request = Twitter::REST::Request.new(TWITTER, :post, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=INIT&total_bytes=#{filesize}&media_type=image/png").perform
media_id = init_request[:media_id]

Twitter::REST::Request.new(TWITTER, :post, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=APPEND&media_id=#{media_id}&media=#{file_path}.png&segment_index=0").perform

Twitter::REST::Request.new(TWITTER, :post, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=FINALIZE&media_id=#{media_id}").perform
```

Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: No-one to give me a hand? :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [examples](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Update.md) in the gem's repo.

If you want to upload with a post, it can be as simple as:

```
client.update_with_media("I'm tweeting with @gem!", File.new("/Users/folder/image.png"))`
```

If you just want to upload and get a reference of media_id, this should work:

```
client.upload(File.new("/Users/folder/image.png"))
```

Comment: Thanks! However update_with_media is deprecated, which is why I am trying this way..

Comment: Oh.. Sorry about that. I've never used this gem. Have you tried using the second approach and then  `client.update("Tweet text", :media_ids => #the_id_from_the_last_call)` ?

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the follow. I haven't tried your method yet, tomorrow I guess. However, I don't have any hint regarding my method... I am sure I am not far, but still investigating

Answer (score 0):

This request is wrong:

```
Twitter::REST::Request.new(TWITTER, :post, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=APPEND&media_id=#{media_id}&media=#{file_path}.png&segment_index=0").perform
```

because you did't upload media file as multi-part data, you only send file path as text.
So, you should use Twitter::REST::Request like this:

```
Twitter::REST::Request.new(TWITTER,
                           :post, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json",
                           command: 'APPEND',
                           media_id: media_id,
                           media: File.open(file_path),
                           segment_index: 0).perform
```